# same code works in loacalhost/server2go but not when i put for hosting

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

hello all this is the code for ajax form submition which shows the error when there is any error otherwise it redirects the page to anothera page .
it works fine when i am working on my localhost(server2go) but when i put it on the host server it just dosent redirects

i want when the callback function receivs the data loginsu4343fu15 it should redirect to mypage.php but it just alers the code

```
  function loginbyajax(){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'loginform_process.php', 
        data:$("#loginme").serialize()+ "&widthis=" + screen.width,
        success: function(data){
        if(data=='loginsu4343fu15'){
        window.location.href = "Mypage.php";
        }else{
        alert (data);
        } 
        }
        });
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: what comes in alert??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this (this is only a possibility)

use this

```
 if($.trim(data)=='loginsu4343fu15'){
```

instead of

```
if(data=='loginsu4343fu15'){
```

trim the white space and check the data.